# C# Reading a file into an array of strings and printing it into a Textbox

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my code as a described it a little bit in the title.

So the thing I want to do is to read a number from a file and printing it into a `TextBox` but the only thing I can get written there is `System.String[]`.

And here is my code:

```
private void ladenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Kontostand aus Datei auslesen und in variable speichern anschließend in tb schreiben

    string[] Kontostand = File.ReadAllLines(pathkonto);

    string tbkontostand = Kontostand.ToString();

    this.lbKontostand.Text = "Kontostand: " + tbkontostand + "€";


    string[] Log = File.ReadAllLines(pathlog);

    string LoginTextbox = Log.ToString();

    this.tbLog.Text = LoginTextbox;
}
```

Maybe i should say that my Kontostand is an label which i want to look like that:

```
Kontostand: 500 €
```

And my file where i want to read that out looks like that:

```
500
```

Thanks for helping me out :)

Timm

Comment: Use [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) (instead of `Log.ToString()`)

Comment: On this line `string LoginTextbox = Log.ToString();` you're calling `ToString()` on an array. If you want to [join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) the array into one string, using comma or a delimiter, try `string LoginTextbox = string.Join(", ", Log);`

Comment: No, do _not_ use `string.Join()` as @Unholy suggests. That's just plain wasteful. you can set the `tbLog.Lines` property directly without any additional effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify, but it appears you're using Winforms. If so, you should use this:

```
    string[] Log = File.ReadAllLines(pathlog);

    this.tbLog.Lines = Log;
```

The default behavior of the `ToString()` method is to just return the name of the type of the object. The `string[]` type does *not* override the default behavior, so that's what you're getting in the text box.

However, the Winforms `TextBox` class has a `Lines` property of type `string[]`. So you just need to set that directly to the `string[]` you get from reading the file.

In your original code, you also want to include in a `Label` file lines from a different source, which you can easily do like this:

```
string[] Kontostand = File.ReadAllLines(pathkonto);

this.lbKontostand.Text = "Kontostand: "
    + string.Join("", Kontostand) 
    + "€";
```

The `Label` control doesn't have a `Lines` property, so in this particular case, you *do* need to use something like `string.Join()`.

Since `Label` controls also don't have a multi-line mode, I simply concatenate the contents of the file with the empty string as the separator. There'd be no point in using `Environment.NewLine` here. You could of course use any string you want instead of `""`. It's up to you.

Now, from your edited question, it appears you may not need any sort of multi-line support at all, because the data you describe is just a single line. If this is in fact the case, your code can be quite a lot simpler (and more efficient):

```
private void ladenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.lbKontostand.Text = "Kontostand: "
        + File.ReadAllText(pathkonto)
        + "€";
    this.tbLog.Text = File.ReadAllText(pathlog);
}
```

For that matter, if you simply want to copy the file contents into the respective controls, that's the way to do it anyway. Reading the contents in an array, only to copy the entire contents of that array into the control, is less efficient than just reading all of the file text and assigning it to the `Text` property directly. New-line characters will be read into the string returned by `ReadAllText()`, so whether the file contents are really multi-line or not, the above should work better than what you were originally trying to do.

Comment: Thanks it works but the first Read file task for my "Kontostand" still doesn´t work!

Comment: Sorry, I was just focused on the second part. See edit above for how you can incorporate both files into your text box lines.

Comment: The First part is a Label :)

Comment: Ah. Well, when there's no [mcve], it's hard to fully understand the code and the intent. That said, if your files really only have a single line in each, and you know this for sure in advance, you can probably dispense with the `Lines` property and just use e.g. `Kontostand[0]` and `Log[0]` where you were previously using `Kontostand.ToString()` and `Log.ToString()`. I assume you've already figured out how to apply the first part to the `Label`...if not, post a comment and I can update the answer to be more appropriate for your specific scenario.

Comment: That would be great

Comment: Okay...see edit again. Again, without a [mcve] it's impossible for me to know what's exactly the best in your case, but I think you may actually prefer the last code example above over the other approaches. Since you don't appear to have any need to manipulate the file text at the per-line level, there's not really any reason to read it as individual lines in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need is to be sure that your TextBox has the *Multiline* property set to true and that you have sized its height enough to see more than one line. 
Next, you don't apply the ToString to an array of strings. This just produces the class name because arrays don't have an override of that method and thus they call the base [Object.ToString().](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Instead you can use [AppendText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to add first the fixed text, then [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) to render the lines of your file followed by the final currency symbol.

```
 private void ladenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string[] Kontostand = File.ReadAllLines(pathkonto);
    this.lbKontostand.AppendText("Kontostand: " + Environment.NewLine)
    this.lbKontostand.AppendText(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,tbkontostand);
    this.lbKontostand.AppendText(" €");
 }
```

Comment: I want the Label to be on one Line

Answer (score 0):

```
string LoginTextbox = string.Join("\r\n", Log);
```

use string.Join to get a comma separated string of all the values in the array.

Comment: The OP wants individual lines in the text box, not comma-delimited text.

Answer (score 0):

`Log.ToString();` just call `ToString` method of a string[] type variable.
you need to loop all strings in your array

```
foreach(string s in Log)
   this.tbLog.Text += s+"\n";
```

Comment: When concatenating strings in a loop, one should _never_ use the `+` operator. Use `StringBuilder` instead. Besides that, suggesting to concatenate the read lines in this particular scenario is very poor advice, whether using `+`, `StringBuilder`, or `string.Join()`, because the lines from the file can be set directly using the `TextBox.Lines` property.

Comment: @PeterDuniho "one should never use" never is may be a little exaggerated. If you have only 10-50 items and you know it, there is no real performance issue at hand

Comment: @MongZhu: I admit it's a matter of opinion. But I wouldn't use string concatenation even with 10 items. Code always evolves, and assumptions you make today almost always change in the future. It's easier to write the code correctly to start with.

Comment: @PeterDuniho "and assumptions you make today almost always change in the future.It's easier to write the code correctly to start with" I agree very much with that statement

Comment: @knuVedid File.ReadAllLines throws any exception?